# JavaScript regex issue for folders names

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to allow alphanumeric strings with hyphens, underscores and spaces allowed. The string must start with a number or a letter and be a maximum total of 20.

Here is my code:

```js
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]){0,20}$/;
    var newName = "12345678901234567890233_pm";
    if (regex.test(newName)) {
        console.log('yes');
    }else{
        console.log('no');
    }
```

My code always returns yes. Is my regex wrong please?

Thanks.

Comment: It returned `no` with your code. would you double-check it?

Comment: Yes, it returned no?

Comment: if I test it with 12345678901234567890233_pm which is 26 chars in length it still returns yes.

Comment: FYI there's no need for the `()` around the `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of the `+` quantifier in the first character class does not do what you seem to think it does - it’s actually not at all necessary in this context. Additionally, since the first character class accounts for `1` of the `20` maximum characters, reduce the maximum quantifier in the second character class to `19`:

```js
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{0,19}$/;
    var newName = "12345678901234567890233_pm";
    if (regex.test(newName)) {
        console.log('yes');
    }else{
        console.log('no');
    }
```